# Get body without tags using tidy

Tags: php, dom, tidy

http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.body.php will return the body content wrapped with the `<body>` tag. How do I get the body content without the `<body>` tag?  I've come up with a couple possible solutions, however, they are not very elegant.

```
$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseString($html);
$tidy->cleanRepair();

$body_content=trim(ltrim(rtrim(trim($tidy->body()->value),'</body>'),'<body>'));
var_dump($body_content);

$body=$tidy->body()->value;
$body_content=substr($body,7,strlen($body)-16);
var_dump($body_content);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$tidy->body()` returns a `tidyNode` instance representing the body. Each `tidyNode` contains a `child` property containing an array of `tidyNode` instances for each child element. You can loop over these children to rebuild the inner html of the body tag. For example:

```
<?php
$html = <<<'HTML'
<html>
    <head><title>test</title></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <p>Hello world!</p>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
HTML;

$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseString($html);
$tidy->cleanRepair();

$bodyInnerHtml = '';
foreach($tidy->body()->child as $child) {
    $bodyInnerHtml .= (string)$child;
}
var_dump($bodyInnerHtml);
```

will result in:

```
string(36) "<h1>Hello!</h1>
<p>Hello world!</p>
"
```

More information about the `tidyNode` class can be found in the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.tidynode.php#tidynode.props.child).

Comment: Thanks Pieter,  Your approach is more elegant, but maybe I will stick with my hack as it is likely much quicker.